# Using grep to pull a series of random numbers from a known line

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a simple scalar file producing strings like...

```
bpred_2lev.ras_rate.PP    0.9413 # RAS prediction rate (i.e., RAS hits/used RAS)
```

Once I use grep to find this line in the output.txt, is there a way I can directly grab the "0.9413" portion? I am attempting to make a cvs file and just need whatever value is generated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to combine finding and extracting into a *single* command:

- `awk` (POSIX-compliant)

  ```
  awk '$1 == "bpred_2lev.ras_rate.PP" { print $2 }' file
  ```
- `sed` (*GNU* `sed` or *BSD/OSX* `sed`)

  ```
  sed -En 's/^bpred_2lev\.ras_rate\.PP +([^ ]+).*$/\1/p' file
  ```
- *GNU* `grep`

  ```
  grep -Po '^bpred_2lev\.ras_rate\.PP +\K[^ ]+' file
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **awk** like this:

```
grep <your_search_criteria> output.txt | awk '{ print $2 }'
```